cutting faces in geometry nodes
What is the best method to cut faces in geometry nodes?
I'm trying to create geometry and distribute it across a face for a 3d printable textured surface.
Is there an equivalent to knife project? Perhaps using the raycast node?
Boolean doesn't work correctly with a non manifold face as one of the operands:


Make it manifold by extruding and merging by distance with old but flipped face, mesh boolean, select by normal only the part that was flipped.

That's a really tricksy hack!
